# Json Web Token, Axios 401-Unauthorized, Django, Vue.js

Tags: django, vue.js

Every time i do a GET request to API from *FrontEnd* or *POSTMAN* to secured (*isAuthenticated*) content, i get 401 error(*Unauthorized*).

**I have two servers:**

> 1.Django, django-rest-framework, with Json Web Token.(API)
>   2.Vue.js

**api endpoints:**

```
Registration (AllowAny):  http://holykrava.hopto.org:8002/user-api/register/
Login (AllowAny): http://holykrava.hopto.org:8002/user-api/get-token/
List of Users (IsAuthenticated): http://holykrava.hopto.org:8002/user-api/user-list/
```

**Vue-Part**

```
<script>
//import {HTTP} from './http-common';
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  created() {
    //let tokenOld = localStorage.getItem('token')
    let token = this.$store.state.token
    axios.get(
    'http://holykrava.hopto.org:8002/user-api/user-list/',
    {headers: {
        authorization: token
      }}
    )
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

> Chrome Dev Tool (Network-Logs)
>
> General-Headers:

```
Request URL: http://holykrava.hopto.org:8002/user-api/user-list/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: 188.190.62.145:8002
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

> Request-Headers:

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Im11dGFwdXRhIiwiZXhwIjoxNTMxODUxODg0LCJlbWFpbCI6IiIsIm9yaWdfaWF0IjoxNTMxNzY1NDg0fQ.LGji_eCDVIvGpQ9xDEO2QAISEEW9FpHVcwRl6Oz9cCM
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/?
```

> Response-Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 58
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 16 Jul 2018 19:34:45 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.4
Vary: Accept
WWW-Authenticate: JWT realm="api"
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

**IT Works in Terminal like this:**
get token:

```
curl -X POST -d "username=userusername&password=userpassword" http://holykrava.hopto.org:8002/user-api/get-token/
```

pass token:

```
curl -H "Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo0MCwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ1c2VydXNlcm5hbWUiLCJleHAiOjE1MzE4NDAxNTAsImVtYWlsIjoiIiwib3JpZ19pYXQiOjE1MzE3NTM3NTB9.SoITxagpmbviEFl_Iy086Jy0KgAUNV0WW-a3wMM_Fos" http://holykrava.hopto.org:8002/user-api/user-list/
```

```
corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware, installed
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

> 

```
Default Authintication Class:
'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication'
```

i spend two days trying to figure out whats wrong, but failed
looking for some1 who can help! thanks.

Comment: The first thing with request headers is missing the `JWT` prefix when compared to the curl request.

Comment: how to include them ?

Comment: Just `'JWT ' + token`?

Comment: u must be kidding me! added prefix jwt and it worked. lol